# Validate uniqueness on a model to a related model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 4 models I'm working with: User, List, Permission, Invitation.

They are related like so:

Users have many lists and Lists have many users, the joining table is the Permission table.
Users can share lists with Invitations. My invitation model looks like so:

```
Invitation(id: integer, list_id: integer, sender_id: integer, recipient_email: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

What I need to do, is when a user creates an invitation, I want to run a check and make sure the recipient user, doesn't already have a permission for the list.

In my Invitation model, I currently have this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :list_id, :scope => :recipient_email, :message => "is already shared with this user"
```

This doesn't work though, because I really need to be looking at the Permission model, and doing this on creation of my invitation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :list_id, :scope => :user_id, :message => "is already shared with that user"
```

Basically, I want to check to see if a relationship already exists between the User and the List before sending an invitation. I can redo the database logic if necessary, I'm just stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my own situation, I've seemed to have figured it out. Here's my custom method/validation and what it looks like in my invitation model:

```
validates :recipient_has_list

   def recipient_has_list
      user = User.find_by_email(self.recipient_email)

      if user.lists.include?(self.list)
        errors.add :list_id, "is already shared with that user"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) will be helpful in this situation.